# Switchable Grails DataSource

Tags: spring, grails

We need to use multiple datasources in grails application. Per user i.e per each http session (from login to logout of user)  the application takes different datasource based on the user's request.

http://www.leebutts.com/2008/07/switchable-grails-datasource.html

The above link provides a good solution for this. We have implemented as said in that page, with modified dynamic configuration.It's working well.

1) But how this code switches the datasource from session to session?
2) What is the use of `ThreadLocal contextHolder` in this code?

Please explain . . .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Grails binds requests to threads. A `ThreadLocal` variable holds a different value for each thread that accesses it (allowing thread safety without synchronization).

So, in his flow what happens is this:

1. User selects an `Environment` in the `EnvironmentController`, which the controller saves into the user's session.
2. The `beforeFilter` he has looks at each request and determines if there is an `Environment` in the user's session. If so, he sets the `EnvironmentHolder` to point to that environment. Since this is a `ThreadLocal`, each thread (in this case: request) can have it's own value.
3. When the `dataSource` bean is accessed, his `SwitchableDatasource` bean selects the correct datasource based upon the value held in the `EnvironmentHolder`'s `ThreadLocal` value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, for each time spring needs dataSource in request processing, it consults the `SwitchableDatasource` bean. The returned dataSource is different for each session. am i correct ?